# Java: Override protected String

Tags: java

I don't know Java.

Just need a quick fix if possible.

How to override protected String?

I have:

```
public class Something {

    protected String changeMe = "this";

    public String viewForm() {
        ...
        return getForm();
    }

    public String getForm() {
        return changeMe;
    }

}
```

myfile:

```
public class MySomething extends Something {

    public String viewForm() {
        return super.viewForm();
    }
}
```

How to use `changeMe = "that"` in class **MySomething**?
Thanks.

Comment: Override is the wrong terminology here. You're just looking to change the value; yes?

Comment: "Overriding" is something you do to methods. For a field, just assign it to something else.

Comment: Not sure why you'd be using java if you didn't know it.

Comment: Your post practically contains the answer. Look at your last sentence and try that out.

Comment: BTW: You don't need to override the viewForm method in the MySomething class if it's doing the same thing as the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, others have answered your question. In case, you are really new to Java struggling to figure it out, the simplest answer to your question is just put your above mentioned statement in the constructor of the derived class:

1. Solution one (actually bad solution):

   ```
   public class MySomething extends Something {
       public MySomething() {
           changeMe = "that"
       }
   }
   ```
2. A better solution for your problem is to define a setter method in the class `Something` as follows (in case you have access to its source code):

   ```
   public void setChangeMe(String newValue) {
       changeMe = newValue;
   }
   ```

and you can change the value by calling

```
Something s = new Something();
s.setChangeMe("that");
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not new to Java, I don't know Java at all :) , I just didn't want to wait Monday for Backend guys to fix this, since it was blocker for my Frontend tasks.

Answer (score 0):

the word override is a hint for the compiler, with that you let it know that you're writing code that at your own way implements the method of a parent class or the interface.

having said that overriding a variable/attribute/field is a wrong use of the terminology, and makes not much sense

to answer your question: you can access toso the **changeMe** object because it is not defined as private... so you can change the value directly..

## Example:

```
public static void main(String args[])   {
    MySomething ms = new MySomething();
    System.out.println(ms.changeMe);
    ms.changeMe = "that";
    System.out.println(ms.changeMe);
}
```

Comment: That's neither an answer to the question, nor anything that hasn't already been pointed out in the comments. Flagged as "not an answer".

Comment: got it.... look the update if you interested

Comment: retracted the vote